# Use Excel cube connection in data model

Tags: microsoft-excel

**Background:**  I have a industry specific database program that is used by a contractor for RMS.  It has a really bad reporting function that does not provide the info that I require.  It also has a data warehouse that provides CUBE data connections for Excel.  While this provides more info, I need to take the DW's output and connect it to other data sources for my reporting needs.

**Question:**  Is it possible to take a live CUBE connection in Excel and add it to the data model to then create relationships?

The connection string starts with `Provider=MSOLAP.8` and the command type is `Cube`

Comment: Try this,, DATA Menu then Existing Connection,,, it brings the list of all the cubes you have connected  previously,, now select the cube you want & hit  Open,, with IMPORT dialogue ,, along with others you find Check box for `Add this to Data Model`. Hope this work for you,, plzz confirm through comments whether it works or not,, then I'l post it as ANSWER !!

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work-the add this to the data model check box is grayed out.

Comment: .. possibly you don't have Power Query Installed !!

Comment: I do have Power Query installed and being used on other parts of the workbook.  There seems to be serious restrictions regarding the use of a Cube and a Pivot Table as a data source.

Comment: ,,, no as such restriction have been applied unless is not active to restrict,,, I'm using frequently,,, try this once use a database either Access ,, SQL or Excel and add it to the Data model & then try the CUBE !!